# Displaying A Twitter User's Timeline

Tags: android, twitter

I have successfully completed this: http://www.sitepoint.com/loading-twitter-data-into-android-with-lists/ tutorial and have gotten my app to display tweets based on a search criteria.

What I want my app to do is display the timeline of a specific user.

From that tutorial I have replaced my get line with this:

```
HttpGet("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=android");
```

I am getting no results in my listview.. I shouldn't need to authenticate user name and password because all I want to do is display the timeline, not manipulate it.

Comment: no I am not, I didn't need to with the search method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Twitter4j this is pretty easy :

```
 public final class GetTimelines {
        /**
         * Usage: java twitter4j.examples.GetTimelines ID Password
         * @param args String[]
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Twitter unauthenticatedTwitter = new TwitterFactory()
                    .getInstance();
            System.out.println("Showing public timeline.");
            try {
                List<Status> statuses = unauthenticatedTwitter
                        .getPublicTimeline();
                for (Status status : statuses) {
                    System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":"
                            + status.getText());
                }
                if (args.length < 2) {
                    System.out
                            .println("You need to specify TwitterID/Password combination to show UserTimelines.");
                    System.out
                            .println("Usage: java twitter4j.examples.GetTimelines ID Password");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                // Other methods require authentication
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(args[0],
                        args[1]);
                statuses = twitter.getFriendsTimeline();
                System.out.println("------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Showing " + args[0]
                        + "'s friends timeline.");
                for (Status status : statuses) {
                    System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":"
                            + status.getText());
                }
                statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline();
                System.out.println("------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Showing " + args[0] + "'s timeline.");
                for (Status status : statuses) {
                    System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":"
                            + status.getText());
                }
                Status status = twitter.showStatus(81642112l);
                System.out.println("------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Showing " + status.getUser().getName()
                        + "'s status updated at " + status.getCreatedAt());
                System.out.println(status.getText());
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (TwitterException te) {
                System.out.println("Failed to get timeline: "
                        + te.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

<sub>Sample taken from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Network/snaio/twitter4j/examples/GetTimelines.java.htm)</sub>

Comment: So how do I get that in my ListView then?

Comment: It returns an List<Status>, use a ListAdapter to sync the contents of the ListView to this List returned.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the answer of ur question at https://github.com/robhinds/AndroidTwitterDemo

or

http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html

use twitter4j jar for same

hope will help u ...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fetch user timeline than the best way is  -

twitter4j jar file - http://twitter4j.org/archive/twitter4j-3.0.3.zip

To register your app go to dev.twitter.com

We can fetch the use timeline by using twitter oauth and for this process we don't need to provide any user credentials

```
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
    builder.setOAuthAccessToken(TWITTER_ACCESS_KEY);
    builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET);
    Configuration configuration = builder.build();
    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
    Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
    Paging page = new Paging();
    page.setCount(100);
    List<Status> statuses = new ArrayList<Status>();
    statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline("write username here", page);
    for (Status status : statuses) {
        System.out.println("title is : " + status.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has introduced Fabric SDK for needs like yours. Here is a site: [Twitter Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/android?locale=en-us). When you install SDK you will have new icon in your Android studio for Fabric Sdk. You have to install Twitter kit and use embed tweets. For user timeline you have to use UserTimeline. Also , you have some project in github that can help you understand how Twitter kit works:
[Github repo](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/tree/master/samples/app/src)